# Show content from current gallery only

Tags: wordpress

I would like to modify the below script in order to post / display the content of the gallery of my current permalink - at the current stage though it displays all images of all galleries. How can I have this changed?

```
        <?php 
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' => 'galleries', 'posts_per_page' => of_get_option('le_gallery_items'), 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') );
        $mod = 1;
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order') );
        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
            $src = $src[0];
        }
        else{
            foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
                $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
            }
        }
         if ($mod % 3 == 0) {
            echo ' <div class="gallery-entry-img-last">';
         }
         else{
            echo ' <div class="gallery-entry-img">';
         }
         ?>
```

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using a plugin like "NextGEN Gallery" ?? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery

Comment: I have a built-in gallery on my WordPress installation , however I am currently trying to alter this. Basically before all galleries were shown and once clicked they would individually open in a shadowbox. I have seen to modify this now and have a gallery open on a new page using the specific permalink, so I am now looking for a method to alter the above mentioned code to display the gallery items of this specific permalink page.

Comment: This gallery that is built-in is actually not a default functionality of WordPress(I can tell that by the `'post_type' => 'galleries'`. Are you on the Gallery page when you want to use this code? If so, just remove the `while` loop and the `$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query(...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all images of the current page only then use this code

```
if ( $images = get_posts(array(
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
{
 foreach( $images as $image ) {
 $attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
 $attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );
 $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
 $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );

 //echoing the attachment  
 echo '<img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt="" />';
 }
}     
else {
     echo "No Image";
}

//to exclude feature image use this
get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

if ( $images = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'exclude' => $thumb_ID))) //exluding feature image by its ID
```

Comment: @IoQ: Your method works as mentioned absolutely fine but I have noticed that the Featured image is being intragted as well. Is there a way to alter your code in order to exclude the featured image? Your expert advise would be truly appreciated.

Comment: You're a true expert! THANK YOU very very much